# Unity Advertising id for mobile

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, unityscript, ads

I want to get google play and IOS advertising id, is there any plugin you can recommend?

I have tried this solution, but it only works on Android:

```
string advertisingID = "";
bool limitAdvertising = false;

AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass  ("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("currentActivity");
AndroidJavaClass client = new AndroidJavaClass ("com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient");
AndroidJavaObject adInfo = client.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject> ("getAdvertisingIdInfo",currentActivity);

advertisingID = adInfo.Call<string> ("getId").ToString();   
limitTracking = (adInfo.Call<bool> ("isLimitAdTrackingEnabled"));`
```

Comment: Have a look at this [Google AdMob](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) guide. You'll need to obtain an Ad Unit ID, see [this](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3052638) for more info. This is just one potential solution, look into other networks as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick McLaren already mentioned Ad mob by google is one solution. If you look into the asset store there are a lot of assets you can use for an easy ad integration in your Unity apps.

For my purposes, AdMob has to low quality ads so i decided to use the [Unity ads](http://unityads.unity3d.com). They provide high quality ad content and it has good documentation. You can get started by downloading their asset for free in the asset store and by looking to the unity ads integration guide asset store. The only minus about unity ads is the missing integration for banners. But you can still use different ad platforms mixed together.

Here a list of some other ad platforms/asset:

1. Kii
2. Chartboost
3. AdColony
4. EveryPlay
5. Playhave
6. Visualtap
7. Flurry
8. Flurry Video
9. Appnext
10. Codefuel
11. Startapp
12. AdBuddiz
13. Admob
14. Nexage
15. AppWiz
16. Revmob
17. Heyzap
18. Tapjoy

and last but not least Prime31.

I hope I could help!
Good luck!

Cheers 
Th3B1gBull

Comment: Thank you for your replies but using custom api (Don't wont to integrate admob or others mentioned above).

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can use [Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.RequestAdvertisingIdentifierAsync.html).

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76279505/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).